# Finding $ \int_{-1}^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx $ where $f(x)=\Bigl\{\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{|\sin(x)|}x,&\text{if }x\ne 0\\1,&\text{if }x=0\end{smallmatrix}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x},  & \text{if $x\ne 0$ } \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $x=0$ }
\end{cases} $$
 Then find the value of $$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,dx $$

Please give me some hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The functuon Is odd, hence...?

Comment: @SewerKeeper I'd enter that as an answer even. I'd upvote that as (an essentially problem solving) hint.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life: After that, the question gets deleted, with all these answers and upvotes...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
The function is  odd, so...?

Comment: So the integral is $0$.